# how to use sqlite3 in Theos application

Tags: iphone, sqlite, jailbreak, theos

I a trying to create a Theos application in which i need to use sqlite,But i don't know how should i import sqlite3 library like we do in Xcode app.
Below is what i did till now and getting error while compiling.

1. added import in `RootViewController.h`
2. extracted `sqlite3.h` and `sqlite3.c` in root of my app from this [Zip](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html)

Trying to figure out from so many days i am new.

Comment: **What** compile error are you getting?  We can't read your mind.  You need to work on improving the information you add to your questions, because they're almost all unanswerable.  You need to add details if you want other people to be able to help you.

Comment: Thanx @Nate suddenly Theos stopped working in my Ios i will update my question with details soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case someone else need,Here what i did to use Sql statement in Theos App, i added

> sqltest_LDFLAGS=-lsqlite3

in makefile and now able to use all the Sql statements.

Answer (score 1):

In Code add this header

```
#import <sqlite3.h>
```

or

```
#include <sqlite3.h>
```

and in makefile add this:

```
NameOfYourApp_LDFLAGS=-lsqlite3
```